# Перенос layout между Activity Android

Tags: java, android

У меня есть item.xml (короткая версия новости), в котором прописаны некоторые поля (заголовок, картинка новости и т.д.). Я использую его в адаптере, для добавления в RecyclerView. При нажатии на элемент списка в RecyclerView открывается полная версия новости, в которой также есть заголовок, картинка новости, аналогичные информации из короткой версии. В full_news.xml прописаны точно такие же поля. Сейчас я передаю данные через:

```
intent.putExtra("title", news.getTitle());
```

И получаю их в полной новости через:

```
getString("title");
```

А потом заново нахожу все поля и выставляю пришедшие данные. Получается, что в двух местах используется один и тот же шаблон и код.

Подскажите, каким способом в Android можно перенести/внедрить шаблон с короткой новостью item.xml в активити/шаблон полной новости?

UPD:
Передаются картинки ImageView, заголовки, короткое описание.

В item.xml использую Layout'ы. Вот часть кода:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/newsTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="News1"
            android:textAlignment="viewStart"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/newsImage1"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/news_logo"
            tools:visibility="visible" />
  </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: вопрос максимально непонятный как по мне, вы кроме title вы что-то передаете?  приложите немного больше кода который будет отображать картину более подробно

Comment: Добавил пример xml. По сути стоит задача перенести LinearLayout (с полями короткой новости) со всем содержимым в активити полной новости по клику на элементе. В первой активити отображается список элементов, во второй полная новость.

Comment: Расшить Activity, в котором найди все что тебе надо. Потом унаследуй от этого класса обе активити и юзай как тебе надо.

Comment: Передавать между активити целиком view-элементы - максимально плохая идея (примерно, как тащить куда то монитор, чтобы показать, что на нем видно). Передавать нужно данные, а не их отображение на экране.то есть сейчас вы все делаете правильно. Так же, как писали выше, вы можете добавить одну разметку в другую через <include> и заполнить ее переданными данными

Comment: Работаю с Android Studio всего два месяца, поэтому ещё много чего не знаю) Спасибо, за ответ. Сейчас стал использовать include для разметки.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если нужно перенести разметку одного файла в другой, то следует использовать `<include />`
Например:

```
<include
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    layout="@layout/item" />
```

Хотя сомневаюсь, что оставлять для полной версии новости ту же разметку - хорошая практика.

Comment: Разметка короткой новости используется как подобие хедера  в полной новости. То есть сначала идёт короткая новость, а под ней полная.
Кроме разметки нужно перенести также данные. Если инклудить разметку таким образом, нужно будет пересылать и данные через intent.putExtra("title", news.getTitle()); и проводить такие же операции, разве что убрать описание шаблона короткой новости из полной. 
А есть ли какой-то вариант, чтобы перенести элемент из списка целиком с данными?

Comment: @DenVebber, не уверен, но можно было бы попровать добавить в каждую короткую новость пустой контейнер (LinearLayout и проч.), а при нажатии на соответствующий элемент добавлять в пустой контейнер нужные представления с данными. Тогда не придётся ничего пересоздавать.